# Come back to form data submitted earlier and update it

Tags: orbeon

I'm new to Orbeon. Perhaps this is a dumb question but I'll ask it anyway: is it possible in Orbeon to change the form data after the first time the form is submitted? I mean, suppose that I'm a student that is using Orbeon to enter some of my personal information into a form. After I submit the data I remember that I forgot some data or informed something wrong and then I want to come back, find the data I placed earlier and update the contents.

Is it possible or am I missing something?

Marcos

Comment: Do mean with Form Runner? If so, yes, of course, you can come back and edit data. In fact, as soon as you have saved the data the URL in your browser changes to the "edit" mode.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way is to define 2 xf:submission.
One for the pre-load of the data of your form, you send it with something like this :

```
<xf:action ev:event="xforms-ready">
            <xf:send submission="preload"/>
</xf:action>
```

the second one you'll use it when you need to save the datas (a save trigger is the most common use-case).

With this, when you come for the first time, your preload submission loads only blanks, your save submissions will save your instance. When you'll come back, this saved instance will be loaded by your 'preload' submission and you'll be able to modify your datas before submitting again.